# CS50 Pset7 portfolio

Tags: php, mysql

Don't understand what should I need to do to fix it. It says associative array is empty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Build your associative array like this:

```
$positions["name"] => $stock["name"];
$positions["price"] => $stock["price"];
$positions["shares"] => $stock["shares"];
$positions["symbol"] => $stock["symbol"];
```